# Select subelements in composite shape in pxm

Tags: pixelmator

I have created a composite shape in Pixelmator: it is a circle with rays around (=sun icon) - all in one layer as shapes elements.

Let's say I should transform some rays by rotating them into precise angle.

My problem is I cannot realise how to select subelements in that layer - sometimes I have success, sometimes I don't. It is inconsistent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a complex shape on a single layer, we suggest you turn off Auto-Select, and zoom into the part of the shape you want to select, and then use the mouse to select the shape.

It is the Auto-Select feature that is sometimes inconsistent, at least in our experience.

Hope that helps. Also check out different tutorials on working with shapes starting with [basic shapes](http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/pixelmator-tip-22-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-the-basics/), which might give you more ideas on how this works.